# Why does some NFC antennas have two transmitters: TX1 and TX2?

Tags: nfc

Why do some NFC-modules have two transmitters? TX1 and TX2?

I really can't find what it's for... I was thinking about Single-end and differential signaling? 
So there would be less noise?

Comment: can you show some example IC ??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about electrical engineering and not related to programming. You might be able to get an answer on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most NFC modules have two transmitter outputs pins. These are not two independent outputs but just the two pins of a single differential output.

The reason why a differential output is preferred by NFC modules is quite simple: It is often needed if the NFC chip only has a small supply voltage (3V is common). Since the output is capacitively coupled to the antenna, the antenna can be driven with twice the voltage compared to a single ended output.

That allows for twice the current, and hence twice the magnetic field in the antenna.